# Change of base differentiation problem

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How would I solve the following differentiation problem.

Differentiate

$$g(x)=\frac{\log_{10}(x)}{x^2}$$

I did this

$$g(x)'=-2x^{-3}\log_{10}(x)+x^{-2}\frac{1}{\ln{10}}\frac{1}{x}$$

But did I do this correctly?

Comment: I suppose $\dfrac{1}{\ln_{10}}$ is a layout accident and you meant $\dfrac{1}{\ln 10}$?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant let me edit it

Comment: Then, yes, you did it correctly. Note that you can write it as $$\frac{1-2\ln x}{x^3\ln 10}.$$

Comment: Excellent thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez : BTW, just about everyone writes $g'(x)$ and not $g(x)'$.  This is not just a matter of style; $g'$ is a function which is applied to $x$.  Sorry for nitpicking, but I think it is better for you to read it here than have some teacher correct you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes, indeed, you're differentiation is correct:

$$g(x)'=-2x^{-3}\log_{10}(x)+x^{-2}\frac{1}{\ln{10}}\frac{1}{x} \iff g'(x) = \frac{1-2\ln x}{x^3\ln 10}.$$

Comment: clean and clear +1

Answer (score 1):

Why did you write ''change of base'' when you didn't change the base?  I would use the change-of-base formula to rewrite $g(x) = \left( \frac{1}{\ln 10} \right) \frac{\ln x}{x^2}$, then use the quotient rule, or use $1/x^2 = x^{-2}$ and the product rule.  That way I don't have to remember derivatives of logarithms with bases other than $e$.

I didn't check whether your answer was correct but I trust the commenters that it was.